# Hosting service using castle windsor wcffacility

Tags: c#, wcf, castle-windsor, ioc-container, wcffacility

I have a basic Contracts project:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IEchoService
{
    [OperationContract]
    string GetUpper(string text);
    [OperationContract]
    string GetLower(string text);
}
```

Service project:

```
public class EchoService : IEchoService
{
    public string GetUpper(string text)
    {
        return text.ToUpper();
    }

    public string GetLower(string text)
    {
        return text.ToLower();
    }
}
```

Self host project:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var container = new WindsorContainer();
        container.AddFacility<WcfFacility>(f => f.CloseTimeout = TimeSpan.Zero);

        container
            .Register(
                AllTypes
                    .FromThisAssembly()
                    .InSameNamespaceAs<IEchoService>()
                    .WithServiceDefaultInterfaces()
                    .Configure(c =>
                               c.Named(c.Implementation.Name)
                                   .AsWcfService(
                                       new DefaultServiceModel()
                                           .AddEndpoints(WcfEndpoint
                                                             .BoundTo(new NetTcpBinding(SecurityMode.None))
                                                             .At(string.Format(
                                                                 "net.tcp://localhost:10333/MyServices/{0}",
                                                                 c.Implementation.Name)
                                                             )))));
        Console.WriteLine("hosting...");
        while (Console.ReadKey().Key != ConsoleKey.Q)
        {
        }
    }
```

When I tried connecting to my service from my client, I get this error msg:

> Could not connect to net.tcp://localhost:10333/MyServices/EchoService.
>   The connection  attempt lasted for a time span of 00:00:02.0904037.
>   TCP error code 10061: No connection could be made because the target
>   machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:10333.

So I checked netstat, and found out that my console service, while able to run, isn't even listening on port 10333. I have no other programs using that port, I have even changed to a few other port nubmers, but it just doesn't show up on netstat.

What could be wrong with my console service? or any configuration settings I might have missed out?